# Python3: What this "%" means in this code?

Tags: python

I'm just study Python 3, and some `%` in his code, see below:

```
def main():
    maxwidth = 100 # limita o numero de caracteres numa célula
    print_start() # chama a função print_start
    count = 0 # cria uma variavel cont 
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
        if count == 0:
            color = "lightgreen"
        elif count % 2:
            color = "white"
        else:
            color = "lightyellow"
        print_line(line, color, maxwidth)
        count += 1
    except EOFError:
        break
print_end() # chama a função print_end
```

What this `elif count % 2:` line means?

Comment: It's the modulus operator, just like in many other languages (C, Javascript, PHP). See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: What are you studying from that doesn't explain what all the operators are?

Comment: humm, thanks for your help

Comment: if count is even then do that thing... Search before you post the questions if it is already available on the web.

Comment: ok, can I delete this post?

Comment: Yes, you can delete your question.

Comment: If one of the answers here solved your problem, you should accept the answer to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [*modulo or modulus operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

It divides the "left" value by the "right" value and returns the [Remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) (the amount left over after an even division).

It's commonly used to solve the problem of doing something *every N iterations or loops*. If I wanted to print a message every 100 loops, I could do this:

```
for i in xrange(10000):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print "{} iterations passed!".format(i)
```

I would see:

```
0 iterations passed!
100 iterations passed!
200 iterations passed!
300 iterations passed!
400 iterations passed!
500 iterations passed!
...
```

In your code, `if count % 2` will act on every other iteration: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9. If `count` was 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8, `count % 2` would return 0 and the expression would be `False`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a modulo operation. Divide it by 2 and if you have a remainder of zero it is an even number. It is used quite often in programming and it is a must to know for any programmer.